# How do I shuffle the rows of a matrix and its corresponding labels?

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm in the early stages of building my first neural network and I'm brand new to python.

I am at a roadblock because I don't know how to write code to shuffle my data with its corresponding labels.  I imported my csv, and I used numpy to create a matrix.  I also created a matrix for my labels

```
filepath = '/My Drive/t_data9(1).csv'
my_data = pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive' + filepath, index_col=0)
my_data_matrix =  np.array(my_data)
labels = [0]*5000 + [1]*5000
labels_matrix = np.array(labels)
```

I can access my data, so it's there.  I just need to mix it up before I can separate out some training and validation rows and throw it in the NN I am buidling with keras.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You may `concat` the **feature** and **labels** into a single data frame and do as follows to shuffle the whole sample:

### Dummy Example

```py
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

my_data.head()
```

```
    A   B   C   D
0   A0  B0  C0  D0
1   A1  B1  C1  D1
2   A2  B2  C2  D2
3   A3  B3  C3  D3
```

And **labels**

```
labels = [0]*2 + [1]*2
my_data['labels'] = labels
my_data.head()
```

```
    A   B   C   D   labels
0   A0  B0  C0  D0  0
1   A1  B1  C1  D1  0
2   A2  B2  C2  D2  1
3   A3  B3  C3  D3  1
```

And **shuffling**:

```py
my_data = my_data.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True) # shuffling 
my_data.head()
```

```
    A   B   C   D   labels
0   A2  B2  C2  D2  1
1   A0  B0  C0  D0  0
2   A3  B3  C3  D3  1
3   A1  B1  C1  D1  0
```